# Listing out all objects/files available on amazon s3 bucket in single call using federated user credentials(or IAM user) on client side by java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How to list out all objects/files information from particular location of amazon s3 bucket  using **federated users credentials** in java. Currently we have the methods for doing this is **AmazonS3Client.listObjects(ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest)**. In this scenario have we other solutions having not to use **BasicSessionCredentials** in client side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Federated user credentials for listing out objects from amazon s3 bucket then make sure you have object READ permission with the federated tokens.